# Strange import behaviour in Python

Tags: python

I have an app. The folders structure (only a part [taken from Rails=)]) is as follows:

```
/app
  __init__.py
  /handlers
    __init__.py
    application_handler.py
    pages_handler.py
/config
  __init__.py
  routes.py
server.py
```

The contents of the app/**init**.py is:

```
from config.routes import HANDLERS

app = Application(
    handlers=HANDLERS,
    debug=DEBUG,
    autoreload=AUTORELOAD,
    template_path=TEMPLATES_PATH,
    static_path=STATIC_PATH,
)
```

The contents of the config/routes.py is:

```
from app.handlers.pages_handler import AboutPageHandler

HANDLERS = [
    (r"^/about$", AboutPageHandler),
]
```

If I run

```
python server.py
```

Everything works fine, the app is started. But for example if I start ipython and enter:

```
from config.routes import HANDLERS
```

I'll see

```
ImportError: cannot import name HANDLERS
```

Can anybody explain such behaviour?

Comment: And if you import and print `config.routes`?

Comment: Got it. Such import lead to recursive imports

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In such a case, the import statements can lead to recursive imports. I did not know that Python will import contents of `__init__.py`